# Why I When I using mailgun for sending from yahoo mail or sending to yahoo mail it not works?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, smtp, mailgun, smtpclient

when i using gmail email it can be reset and set the from recipents
but when using yahoo mail the set from doent send and reset to yahoo address was error with
Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings. "

Comment: please help me if you guys know i have tried and research but this issue doenst found gmail and hot mail, bussiness email it works but on yahoo fail

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out [this page](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN5067.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAHnvGBPPguCFhkSVTvPtYZ19Z3rgamFK-NIvJw-7mFqEG24kI4ilV2nJ3fVD1m1-Es4bSq_7_OPvQc6AZ2bBHU9h7DGvuvioEzBfPzAVkbfXEvqouekcRM4bV5j0k1zaMqeu9hfXUu8o4ZXxzMW7tTb9NXAsuiGcruyjnygnPZZY)?
If this is the cause you could try sending an text-only e-mail for testing purposes, see if that does works.